# How to get original data before modifying?

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

I have simple editAction for Product Entity. It works fine in original, standard way but I need some special verifying before I persist Product after editing. Product has few prices in separated fields. In project I have general setting "minimal price" for products. Before I save Product after editing I want to compare prices with "minimal price". I do it this way:

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Product $pr1, UserInterface $op)
{
    // 1
    $pr_original = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Product::class)->getProductById($pr1->getId());

    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ProductType', $product);
    $form->handleRequest($request); 

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        // 2
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($product);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect(path('product_list'));
}
```

In 2 there is place where I'm comparing values. But the problem is... I can't get original values to compare with. In 1 I want to get original Product but it's going to `$pr_original` with already changed values! That's weird because I see directly in database that object still has original values. So I think that Symfony doesn't make new query to database. So what to do now? How to make Symfony gets me original object?

Comment: Doctrine has what is known as a unit of work cache.  Each time you query with the same id you always get back the exact same object.  Consider cloning your entity:  $prOriginal = clone $pr1;

Comment: I'd like to add that the `preUpdate` Doctrine event allows you to get changeset https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#preupdate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand what Doctrine does for you. ORM's are not easy-query creators. They map the state of your database to in-memory objects that your code understands and is able to work with.

So, when you pass a form like you did, doctrine queries for the object and updates the values in the objects's state. So after the form is processed, your object already has a different state than the one in the database. The only thing left for doctrine to do is persist and flush, or, in other words, register that the state change will be reflected in the database (persist) and actually change the db values (flush).

If you query for an object that is "managed" (meaning, that has already been queried for and is in doctrine's memory) then doctrine will give you the in-memory object, for the sake of efficiency. It will not query the db for that again. You can call the [refresh method](https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/ObjectManager.php#L93) in the manager for updating an object's state from the database, but that will mean to lose the state that has not yet been persisted, like the data that is coming from your form.

What I would recommend in this case is either to create a form event that will compare the value the user wrote with your system value. The form event has to be `preSetData` since you want to make the comparison before your Entity is updated with the new data. You can check more of that here [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html)

The other alternative is to create a custom validation constraint. If your system value is fixed, you can validate that with a custom validator. Or even, with the normal [Comparison Constraints](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#comparison-constraints).

Hope this info helps!

Comment: Very doubtful that the preSetData event actually gives you a before/after  set of objects to compare.  Perhaps a bit of code might make things easier?  And yes the question is confusing as the desired code does not match the description of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for @Cerad - your comment is solution:

Doctrine has what is known as a unit of work cache. Each time you query with the same id you always get back the exact same object. Consider cloning your entity:

```
$prOriginal = clone $pr1;
```

It's working well for me.